# $|2-|1-x||=|x^2-1|$ equation, incorrect solution

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[image]

When I solved this equation I got $x_1 = -1$, $x_2 = 0$ and $x_3 = \frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{2}$

I solved it like this: I first sketched a graph and I could see that the first two solutions were trivial, I got the third one by solving $x^2-1 = -(x-3)$ for $x > 1$, since I could see from my graph that there was an intersection.

Wolfram alpha only displays the first two solutions and doesn't mention the third one, is my solution to the whole problem incorrect?
I also have a question, how do you view if someone solves a problem by sketching a graph and solves it from there and doesn't do all the required calculation work to show that the expression inside every absolute value can be negative and what happens if it is positive and does everything from there.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Wolfram gives me all three solutions.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Are my solutions correct then, looks like there is an error with mine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alpha does all computations in the complex and it turns out that the solution includes a whole locus with a terribly complicated expression (because the equation is equivalent to a quartic one). But that locus certainly includes the third real root.

Now the following Alpha request will give you the three real roots: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=real+roots+of+abs%282-abs%28x-1%29%29-abs%28x%5E2-1%29

Comment: Thank you, I had trouble with the correct input. What is your point of view to solve a problem like this with graphing and not calculating every absolute value ?

Comment: @BiliDebili: this is acceptable, but only if you discuss the number of roots given the degree of the polynomial pieces, to make sure that no root could be forgotten.

Comment: What are polynomial pieces in my problem. Does it mean, that I write a polynomial $(x+1)(x+\frac{-1+\sqrt{17}}{2})x$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Make use of the built-in $RealAbs$ to get correct results from WolframAlpha.

Same results with

$Reduce[RealAbs[2 - RealAbs[1 - x]] == RealAbs[x^2 - 1]]$

$x == -1 || x == 0 || x == \frac{1}{2} (-1 + \sqrt{17})$

There is no general rule. I won't give one. Follow the ideas from Your instructours as close as possible. Read problems carefully. Mathematica can be done sorrow and comprehensive. Sometimes it is really hard to get best practices solutions on the internet. RealAbs or Abs are built-in of different signature. The signature is something that makes object oriented functions different even if the name of the functions are the same. A concept from inheritence. For mathematicians at the starter level this is very strange. RealAbs take only reals, while Abs expects complexes as input and treats the input that methodology process along.

That is nothing really complicated as long as one knows that differences and built-ins exist. But no mathematician is commonly informed that way.  This problem is not included even in complexity theory. It is a jump in thoughts and knowledge that is not connected. There is no work around Abs else than using Assumption or Assuming even this tread the problem different and new problems arise.

Gather as much information as possible and search for problems similar to yours untill you are satisfied or your instructors and judges are satisfied. You can not cover everything at first attempts and the path is the target or goal.

A graphics has only illustrative purposes unless it is required by the problem. It guides a solution or represents the solution. Mathematica is often quite concise and very little proving in the output. This is all left to the interpretation of the operator of the packages.

For such a problem. Ask Wolfram Alpha first about each of the functions on both sides of the equal. Then use the intevals given there for a case study. Then solve the equation on this intervals.

```
PiecewiseExpand[
 RealAbs[2 - RealAbs[1 - x]] == RealAbs[x^2 - 1], , -2 < x < 2]

(-x + x^2 == -2 && x > 3) || (-x + x^2 == 2 && 
   x == 1) || (-x + x^2 == 2 && x == -1) || (-x + x^2 == 2 && x <= 1 &&
    x + x^2 == 0) || (x > -1 && x < 1 && x + x^2 == 0) || (x > 1 && 
   x <= 3 && x + x^2 == 4) || (x < -1 && x + x^2 == 0)
```

Solve on each interval and the put it all together.

Answer (score -1):

Your method is very good but it is not considered a rigorous proof. You can use the graph to turn this into a rigorous proof. We see on the graph that there are only three cases to study: $x\lt -1$ and  $-1\le x \le 1$ and $1 \le x$. Each of these three cases is very easy to study.

Comment: There are four cases to study, $x>3$ is different.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh yes you're correct there is also $x\gt 3$.

Comment: I understand, but there is A LOT of writing. You have two options for $|1-x|$ and the again two options for every one of those for the outside absolute value...

Comment: @BiliDebili: you have no idea what "a lot" means. People sometimes spend years on a computation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I understand, so it's always better to compute rigorously than to draw and skip calculations.

Comment: Many proofs in mathematics come from turning into a rigorous argument what they see on a drawing. The graph tells you plenty of things: the number of solutions, which intervals to study. Use it as a guide for intuition.

Comment: @BiliDebili: no, if you know what you are doing, a graph may be enough.